.net MAUI DataTemplate's. Command Bindings in Parents View Model
I have a ContentView which contains a CollectionView.
...
             xmlns:templates="clr-namespace:PropertyManagement.Portfolio.DataTemplates"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PropertyManagement.Portfolio.ContentViews.ViewModels"
             x:Class="PropertyManagement.Portfolio.ContentViews.AgreementListView">


    <ScrollView>
        <CollectionView x:DataType="vm:AgreementListVM" x:Name="MyCollectionView"  ItemsSource="{Binding AllAgreements}" Margin="10,0">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <templates:AgreementListViewDataTemplate />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </ScrollView>

The DataTemplate contains a few databound Labels and an ImageButton
<Border
    x:Class="PropertyManagement.Portfolio.DataTemplates.AgreementListViewDataTemplate"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:models="clr-namespace:PropertyManagement.Portfolio.Models"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PropertyManagement.Portfolio.ContentViews.ViewModels"
    x:DataType="models:Agreement">

    <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Start" Padding="10">
        <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Start" Spacing="10">
            <Label FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <Label FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Tenant.FirstName}" />
            <Label FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding LetProperty.Address1}" />
            <ImageButton
                Source="edit.png"
                WidthRequest="15" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</Border>

This all works just fine.
Now i want to bind the image button Command to an ICommand (RelayCommand using CommunityToolkit) which is in the parent ContentViews view model ie AgreementListVM.
If I use Command="{Binding Source={vm:AgreementListVM}, Path=EditAgreementCommand}"
then that works correctly, but that requires the DataTemplate to know about the parent view's ViewModel. I want the Data Template to be useable without relying on knowing the viewmodel to use.
I have tried
Command="{Binding EditAgreementCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:AgreementListVM}}}" as described here[ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings?view=net-maui-8.0#bind-to-an-ancestor]
It doesnt work, no binding failures just doesn't fire the relay command and it still requires knowing the viemodel to use.
I have tried
Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:AgreementListVM}}, Path=EditAgreementCommand}"
Project compiles and runs, intellisense even knows that it is an IRelayCommand but the command does not fire and it still requires knowing the view model. It'm wondering why I would use thesewhen the working code seems so much simpler?
Tried this, which would be exactly what I want!
Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyCollectionView}, Path=BindingContext.EditAgreementCommand}" as described here [https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/17771]
Compiles and runs but I get a binding failure
'BindingContext' property not found on 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ReferenceExtension', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ImageButton.Command'    C:\Users\kev12\OneDrive\Documents\Current Projects\MAUI\PropertyManagement\Portfolio\DataTemplates\AgreementListViewDataTemplate.xaml.
Doing my head in!! Can somebody please point out what I am doing wrong?
PS Doesnt change anything if I assign the Content Views viewmodel in the code behind
    public AgreementListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new AgreementListVM();
    }


You try to use TemplateBinding.

@JianweiSun-MSFT No I haven't. It did occur to me but I've been concentrating on the examples that I found. Do you think I should be using TemplateBindings?

You can try the following code:
File structure like this:

Models/NameId.cs:
public class NameId
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
}

ViewModels/BaseViewModel.cs:
public class BaseViewModel
{
     public ObservableCollection<NameId> NameIdList { get; set; }


    public ICommand AddCharCommand { get; private set; }
     public BaseViewModel()
     {
         NameIdList = new ObservableCollection<NameId>
         {
     new NameId { Id = "Id A", Name = "Name A" },
     new NameId { Id = "Id B", Name = "Name B" },
     new NameId { Id = "Id C", Name = "Name C" }
         };
         AddCharCommand = new Command(Addc);
     }


    private void Addc(object obj)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("click");
     }
}

DataTemplates/CardViews.cs:
public class CardView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty NameProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Name), typeof(string), typeof(CardView), string.Empty);

   public static readonly BindableProperty IDProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ID), typeof(string), typeof(CardView), string.Empty);

   public string Name
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(NameProperty);
        set => SetValue(NameProperty, value);
    }

   public string ID
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(IDProperty);
        set => SetValue(IDProperty, value);
    }
}

Create a ControlTemplate in App.xaml:
<Application ...
             xmlns:m="clr-namespace:MauiApp5.Models"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiApp5.ViewModels"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp5"
             x:Class="MauiApp5.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                ....
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <ControlTemplate x:Key="AgreementListViewControlTemplate">

                <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Start" Padding="10" BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Start" Spacing="10">

                        <Label FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Label FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding ID}" />
                        <ImageButton
                                    Source="kb.png"
                                    Aspect="AspectFill"
                                    WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"
                                    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:BaseViewModel}}, Path=AddCharCommand}"/>

                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

Consume AgreementListViewControlTemplate in Specific page:
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiApp5.ViewModels"
             xmlns:m="clr-namespace:MauiApp5.Models"
             xmlns:templates="clr-namespace:MauiApp5.DataTemplates"
             x:Class="MauiApp5.NewPage1"
             Title="NewPage1">
    
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:BaseViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding NameIdList}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <templates:CardView Name="{Binding Name}"
                                        ID="{Binding Id}"
                                        ControlTemplate="{StaticResource AgreementListViewControlTemplate}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>

And here is the effect. When you click the imagebutton, it will print "click" in Output.

Thank-you for your time on this. I will try this as soon as I can and let you know.

Worked perfectly! Thank-you, going to do a lot more learning on Control Templates now.
